# span or paragraph inside a ref using HAML

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm using HAML to create HTML which should look something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="clearfix flatbanner half">
      <a href="my_url" class="my_class1">
        <p class='my_class2'>link_text</p>
      </a>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: 'p' may also be 'span'

Using HAML I already have something like this:

```
= link_to_if(bool_expression, "link_text", "my_url", class: "my_class1", style: "background: url('my_image_url') no-repeat center right;") do
  = link_to("my_url", class: "my_class1") do
    = some_error_handling
```

which produces something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="clearfix flatbanner half">
      <a href="my_url" class="my_class1">link_text</a>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

So I have to add some code to add the 'paragraph' section with class="my_class2" within the 'link' section. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Found it:

replace 

    "link_text"

with

    'content_tag(:div, "link_text", :class => "my_class2")'

Answer (score 1):

In that case, I will suggest using `%a` instead of Rails's `link_to` helper as:

```
= link_to_if(bool_expression, "link_text", "my_url", class: "my_class1", style: "background: url('my_image_url') no-repeat center right;") do
  %a{:href => "my_url", :class => "my_class1"}
    %p.my_class2
      link_text
```